# Bug writing accents in tags

Tags: bug

[In this question I've made a tag edition](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/8/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-mau-e-mal). I've wrote "gramática", and the result was two tags, "gram" and "tica".